# Promise from Apex function in Lightning Web Component LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to use the result of an apex function in a LWC. The apex function returns a promise. I tried wrapping the apex into an async/await function to be able to access the result, but to no avail. Any ideas?

hellohello.cls

```
public with sharing class hellohello {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String hellohello() {
        return 'Hello';
    }
}
```

tester.js

````
import hellohello from '@salesforce/apex/hellohello.hellohello';

export default class Tester2 extends LightningElement {
    
    @api recordId = '';

    async Makeitwork(){
        let ttt = await hellohello();
        return ttt;
    }
    foo = this.Makeitwork();
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
    foo = this.Makeitwork();
```

Only returns the original promise. Instead, you'd have to use `connectedCallback`:

```
async connectedCallback() {
  this.foo = await this.Makeitwork();
}
```

Note that `foo` is guaranteed to be undefined until at least one `renderedCallback` life cycle has occurred.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you elaborate a bit more, like how do I call this connectedCallback?

Comment: @NewStudent2023 `connectedCallback()` is a [lifecycle hook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_lifecycle_hooks) and is automatically called during the appropriate lifecycle event. All you need to do is make sure you match the function name exactly (case-sensitive).